# I want to show my externalurl link coming from api in webview in my application

Tags: java, android, external

My Code :

My Adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SliderAdapter.SliderHolder holder, int position) {
        final HomePage.ContentList item = homePageList.get(position);
          SliderHolder viewHolder = (SliderHolder) holder;
          viewHolder.txt_category.setText(item.getCategoryName());
          viewHolder.title_item_list_pager.setText(item.getTitle());
          if (item.getImage() != null)
              Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(item.getImage()).into(viewHolder.img);
          Log.d("TEST103-2", "PV");
          viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewsDetail.class);
                  intent.putExtra("newsdetail",homePageList.get(position).getExternalUrl());
                  v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                  }
          });

     }
```

news detail class

```
package com.platin.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class NewsDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView newsdetail;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_detail);

        newsdetail = findViewById(R.id.newsdetail);
        newsdetail.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        newsdetail.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("newsdetail"));

    }
}
```

I want to show my externalurl link coming from api in webview in my application.
When I click for detail, it opens on google chrome. but I want it to show in application.

Comment: Please don't just repeat your plea for help, when the quality filter tells you that you need more information. You posted some code. What does it do and what does it not do, that you want to achieve? What have you done? Read [ask] and [edit] your question to include the missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `setWebViewClient` in your `WebView` also you can enable javaScript

```
webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra(LINK));
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and Clint is:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
}
```

Comment: What does the MyWebViewClient class do? What should I add in this class? @MoklesurRahman

Comment: sorry about that I forget to add the clint class answer edited.

Comment: You can use the WebViewClient 's all Override method check the link https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java